# What chmod for files for cron job?>

Tags: php, cron, chmod

as in topic. I know, 777 must work. 755 should too, but what chmod is recommended for cron job? This is php file on server in main directory. 644 not working, permission denied. Rest is ok in this cron job. Thanks for your help! I checked other threads, but no clear response I found.

Comment: You can't ever execute a `644` file, `cron` or not.

Comment: Of course, 644 was just standard chmod for all files on server in installed script. So, I need other chmod for cron job. And here is my question - what chmod? :) I am chmod begginer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on under which user you are adding this crontab entry. That user should be able to read and execute the file. If you want anyone to run the file, your ending digit for the permission must be odd (5 to be exact)

Comment: Sorry, but I am not so strong in cron jobs. This is server job. Ftp user? Admin? I have cron job in my cpanel as ftp user.

Comment: Well, try giving it 755 then - it means anyone will be able to execute it. To restrict it to only the right user, try 744.

Comment: 744 looks best for me, I will try this. Need few minutes for checking/log.

Comment: `744` is great as long as the file is `chown`'d to the correct user.

Comment: Yes don't forget to change the owner of the script that is run to your ftp user.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how do you access the file. If you're passing its path as a parameter to php, it should be only read by the crontab user; if you're running it, it should be read and executable by the user.